# How to play base64 audio string through speakers in nodeJs

Tags: node.js, audio, base64, speaker

I have a web audio chat that sends audio between clients through the server via socket io. When the audio data is sent to the other clients, it also sends the audio base64 string to a UDP port. How can I receive this audio on the second node app and play it in real-time when it gets that string?

I have tried the speaker package but either that will not play the string directly or I did not do it correctly.